# spray json nested class unable to deserialize

Tags: scala, spray, spray-json

Unable to deserialize this using spray . I am unable to understand why the defaultJson protocol does not work. Please note I am new to scala and spray.

```
case class Job(param1:Boolean,param2:String,joblist:List[JobList])

case class 
JobList(param3:String,param4:Option[Seq[Map[String,String]]],....,param10)

implicit  object transformJson extends JsonFormat[Job]{

override def read(json: JsValue): Job = json match {
  case JsObject(fields) =>
    Job(fields("param1").convertTo[Boolean],
      fields("param2").convertTo[String],
      fields("jobslist").convertTo[List[JobList]]
    )

  case _ => deserializationError("Not a Record")
}

override def write(obj: Job): JsValue = ???
```

}

> Error:(55, 39) Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for
>   Boolean
>           Job(fields("param1").convertTo[Boolean], Error:(55, 39) not enough arguments for method convertTo: (implicit evidence$1:
>   spray.json.JsonReader[Boolean])Boolean. Unspecified value parameter
>   evidence$1.
>           Job(fields("param1").convertTo[Boolean]

I tried this first

```
object transformJson extends DefaultJsonProtocol{
     implicit val job=jsonFormat3(Job)
     implicit val joblist=jsonFormat7(JobList)

      }
```

> Error:(53, 39) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of
>   type TransformJson.JF[Array[joblist]]
>       implicit val jobformat=jsonFormat3(Job) Error:(53, 39) not enough arguments for method jsonFormat3:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course I was not telling how to handle JobList

```
case class Job(param1:Boolean,param2:String,joblist:List[JobList])

case class JobList(param3:String,param4:Option[Seq[Map[String,String]]],....,param10)
object TransformJobList extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit val joblist= jsonFormat7(JobList)
    implicit  object transformJson extends JsonFormat[Job]{

    override def read(json: JsValue): Job = json match {
        case JsObject(fields) =>
            Job(fields("param1").convertTo[Boolean],
                fields("param2").convertTo[String],
                fields("jobslist").convertTo[List[JobList]]
            )

        case _ => deserializationError("Not a Record")
    }

    override def write(obj: Job): JsValue = ???
    }
}
```